# favourite and unfavourite image in recyclerview gets in initial state when scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler adapter in which there are  3 image buttons, one of them is for favorite and unfavorite. when the recyclerviews loads its loads proper also when I click on favorite it stores in my favorite list. But the problem is that when I scrolled it the states of image button changes to load time images.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the code for your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting favorite/unfavorite at `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: thanks for you reply i have already placed it in the onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView efficiently recycles views while you scroll.

when you maintain this kind of scenario, where image view can have Fav or UnFav images. you need to maintain both in onBindVIewHolder() method such as

```
if (isFav) {
viewHolder.yourImage.setBackgroundDrawable(FavImage);
} else {
viewHolder.yourImage.setBackgroundDrawable(UnFavImage);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply i have already tried for this. on click it is changing but the problem is on scrolled when i scroll it all the default states of the icon is restored.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image on the #onBindViewHolder on every case (don't assume that you know the current state).